# Spinner en Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo un `Spinner` en un `Fragment`, que al hacer click en un item del `Spinner` me lleva a otro `Fragment`. Pero cuando ejecuto la app, se va directamente al primer item del `Fragment`. No me muestra el `Fragment` que tiene el `Spinner`, si no que de una vez me abre la primera opción del `Spinner`.

Añado el código del `Spinner`

```
public class Bajar_Peso extends Fragment {

public Bajar_Peso() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bajar__peso, container, false);

    Spinner spinnerA , spinnerB;
    String[] Frutas;
    String[] Vegetales;

    Button secreto;

    secreto=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_secreto);

    spinnerA = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_Frutas);
    spinnerB=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_Vegetales);

    Frutas = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Bjar_PesoA);
    Vegetales=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Bjar_PesoB);

    //SPINNER PARA LAS FRUTAS.
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Frutas);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerA.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    //SPINNER PARA LOS VEGETALES
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Vegetales);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerB.setAdapter(adapter);


    //SELECCION DE LAS FRUTAS
           //SELECCION DE LOS VEGETALES
    spinnerB.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {


           if(position==0)
           {
               getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,new BP_Zanahorias()).commit();
           }


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });


    secreto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    return view ;
}
}
```

Comment: Vas a tener que dar un poco mas informaciones. En Android es recomendable de compartir la `Activity`, los componentes y los layouts en la mayoría de los casos. Así solamente se puede deducir que cuando se usa el `Spinner` y se elige posicion == 0, se abre BP_Zanahorias(). Eso no es que quieres? Que quieres entonces?

Comment: ok, Tengo un´Fragment' llamado, Bajar_Peso.java con el respectivo 'Layout'. Entonces al momento de ejecutar la app inicia con un menú, ahí selecciono un item el cual habré el 'Fragment' Bajar_peso y ahí muestra el Layout donde se encuntra el 'Spinner', al seleccionar un item del 'Spinner' me llevaria a BP_Zanahorias, pero en ves de mostrarme el Layout de Bajar_peso habré directamente en  BP_Zanahorias().

Comment: Actualizo codigo

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que `onItemSelected`también se ejecuta cuando la vista esta creada. Una manera simple para remediar eso sería agregar un marcador tipo boolean en el fragmento y ignorar la primera llamada:

```
boolean inicio = true;
```

y en el listener:

```
       if(position==0)
       {
           if (!inicio){
               getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().
               beginTransaction().
               replace(R.id.content_main,new BP_Zanahorias()).commit();
           } else {
               inicio=false;
           }
       }
```

Comment: Lo intente, y me muestra el Layout que contiene el Spinner, pero a la hora de seleccionar el item no funciona

Comment: Hiciste una depuración? Podrías colocar un Log en el listener y en el `onCreateView` del fragmento.

Answer (score 0):

Primero se debe agregar un elemento vacio a las opciones del spinner para representar que no se ha seleccionado nada.

```
Frutas = ["", "manzana", "banana", ...];
Verduras = ["", "zanahoria", "pepino", ...];
```

Y luego onItemSelected debe ser:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
    if(position != 0) { // la primer opcion es la vacia.
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,new BP_Zanahorias()).commit();
    }
}
```